# Creating a soap Request in java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am creating a soap request in java. Basically I am calling a soap service from my rest api.
I have to create a request which should like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:impl="http://impl.service.payment.wallet.paytm.com/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <mid>125FD26C</mid>
      <phone>9958127957</phone>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <impl:withdraw>
         <operationType>WITHDRAW_MONEY</operationType>
         <request>
            <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode>
         </request>
      </impl:withdraw>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am having problem in creating Headers.

```
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
        soapHeader.addChildElement("mid").addTextNode(merchantGuid);
        soapHeader.addChildElement("phone").addTextNode("9958127957");
```

But this is giving me error that `HeaderElements must be namespace qualified`.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite complex to deal with XML Documents, but this is how, you need to do.

```
SOAPHeader header = request.getSOAPHeader();
//Get the document
Document doc=header.getOwnerDocument();
//Create first tag mid and its value    
Element el1=doc.createElement("mid");
el1.setTextContent(merchantGuid);

//Create second tag and its value
Element el2=doc.createElement("phone");
el2.setTextContent("9958127957");

//Add both tags to the SOAPHeader   
header.appendChild(el1);
header.appendChild(el2);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. can you please tell me type of these things : 1. request 2. Document 3. Element . I have tried to use org.wc.dom.Document but it is givng error in setTextContent

Comment: `import org.w3c.dom.Document;import org.w3c.dom.Element;import org.w3c.dom.Node; import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;`. request is envelope in your case.